# Get value on redis expire - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am using Redis in nodejs, and when something expires I use the following code to be notified:

```
module.exports.expire = (callback) => {
    const expired = () => {
        const sub = redis.createClient({url: redisPath})
        sub.subscribe('__keyevent@0__:expired', () => {
            sub.on('message', (channel, message) => {
                callback(message)
        })
    })
}

 const pub = redis.createClient({ url: redisPath })
 pub.send_command('config', ['set', 'notify-keyspace-events' , 'Ex'], expired())
}
```

When something expire I get the event but only the key and not the value. Does anyone know a way to get the key + value when something expires.

Thanks

Comment: Redis Key Space notification only provides the Key. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Both the key and value on expire - is this possible?

Comment: It's can't be done as is, but what is the use case? What do you need the value for?

Comment: It's to get a Channel ID for a discord bot on expiry.

Comment: Try to use combination of a hashtable and simple kv to find the value for the given key.